# Error when testing my first Aurelia plugin

Tags: aurelia

I am having trouble creating my first Aurelia plugin.  When testing it out in a new, clean Aurelia CLI project, `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'target.__useDefault')` is displayed in the browser error console.

When calling `ensureOriginOnExports(executed, name)` in `vendor-bundle.js`, `executed` is `undefined`.

Here's the steps I used:

1. Downloaded the [zip from github](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-plugin).
2. Unzipped and renamed the folder to `aurelia-plugin-test`.
3. Followed the directions on the skeleton github page.
4. Changed the name in `package.json` to `aurelia-plugin-test`.
5. Re-ran `gulp build`.
6. Published to npm: `npm publish ./`.
7. Created a brand new Aureali CLI project.
8. Installed the plugin: `npm install aurelia-plugin-test --save`.
9. Added the following in `aurelia.json`:

   {
       "name": "aurelia-plugin-test",
       "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-plugin-test/dist/amd",
       "main": "aurelia-plugin-test"
   }
10. Added `aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-plugin-test');` into the `configure` function in `main.js`.
11. Ran `au run` and got the error when loading my plugin.

So I'm just using the skeleton without any code changes.  So it just contains the hello-world custom element.

Comment: Did you figure this one out?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I have not. I ended up not using a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In your **aurelia.json** add the following "resources" to the bundle config:

```
{ 
   "name": "aurelia-plugin-test", 
   "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-plugin-test/dist/amd", 
   "main": "aurelia-plugin-test",
   "resources": [
      "hello-world.js",
      "hello-world.html"
   ] 
}
```

Comment: Tried adding resources and I'm getting the same error.